# How to restrict mat-form-field (matInput) user enter only characters and special characters not number?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

[Input Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OSOo.png)I have an matInput field i would like to restrict the input to enter characters & special characters only, not numbers.i am apply
patterns, error msg also comes "plz enter characters only " after that when i click on submit button, forms submitted, i want to stop form submission when errors on the form controls.

Comment: Show us the code you have you tried so far, and the errors do you get.

Comment: i am not getting any errors, my form submitted successfully, when we enter username as numbers 1111 it also submitted, i would like to stop this numbers input, forms submitted only username is characters.

Comment: Show us your code. Edit your original question and include it your code. So that people can understand what are you trying to do and figure up what's not correct.

Comment: It's a common practice to put you code as text in the original question; not as an image. If you are asking for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Remember that this community is made possible by volunteers. Here some guidelines on how to ask your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...follow them helps yourself to get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Pattern" attribute, where you can put your regex to match the the valid input

Or you can create a custom directive and detect the input and not allow the numbers to be inputted by matching the input with the regex

Reference: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

Regex to be used: ^([^0-9]*)$

To test the regex: https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Okay so, what is it that which is not working after applying the above solution?

Comment: Yes but what is the issue with the solution given by me, You said it is not working.
So is there any error or what? Share the screenshot or code.

Comment: You should put [disabled]="formname.invalid" inside your submit button so that it doesn't allow you to submit the form.

Comment: after all field input enter properly , submit button does not enable, it is disabled.

Comment: show me your console.log(this.formaname) results after filling all the fields